# Не помогает list-style-type: none

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Народ, помогите! Есть сайт построенный на 1С Битрикс. Создаю обычный html список на странице. Применяю через **!important;** стиль **list-style-type: none !important;** и о чудо, ни фига не пропадает точка. По видимому где-то в шаблонных стилях перекрывается стиль моего списка. Мот кто знает какое-нить решение. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите стили страницы в инспекторе.

Firefox 12 меню Инструменты->Веб разработка->Инспектор.
Далее выделяете на странице элемент, нажимаете внизу кнопку "стиль" и видите каком файле какая строка меняет стиль.

Comment: Помогло :), но смена стиля у списка в главном стилевом файле, сносит все списки на сайте, пришлось воспользоваться OL.

Comment: т.е. главный стилевой файл имеет приоритет, тут что-то не так

Comment: @archi_sova:
>смена стиля у списка в главном стилевом файле, сносит все списки на сайте

а вы не знаете что такое класс? Примените его и всё ОК :)